# How to concatenate strings in a cell array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation, cell

I am trying to concatenate strings in a cell array using repmat in matlab.

What I want to do is something like:

```
aa={'xx','yy',repmat({'zz'},1,3)}
```

with the result equivalent to:

```
aa={'xx','yy','zz','zz','zz'}
```

but instead the result is:

```
{'xx','yy', {1x3 cell array} }
```

I realize that if I had a variable such as `C=repmat('zz',1,3)` then I could do

```
aa{'xx','yy',C{:}}
```

but the problem is I don't want to define any other variables like C. I want to do this in line if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

use vector concatenation:

```
aa=[{'xx','yy'},repmat({'zz'},1,3)]

aa = 
    1×5 cell array

     'xx'    'yy'    'zz'    'zz'    'zz'
```

Comment: Good. This works, but is there no way to do this with a function on repmat? What I was hoping for is a function that takes a cell array and converts it into a comma separated list, i.e. that reproduces the C{:} behavior. For example: colonoperator(repmat({'zz'},1,3)) that outputs a comma separated list.

Comment: @BenBarrowes You honestly can't.  Why are you opposed to temporary variables?

Comment: does `reshape([{'xx','yy'},repmat({'zz'},1,3)],[],1)` work for you?

Comment: I tried using subsref to get a comma separated list from a cell array, but that does not seem to work for cells though it does for numerical arrays:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/vbpSkrPVa7A
user2999345 your suggestion also works, but I was hoping for a function that operates on a cell array to produce a comma separated list.